# Calculating the sum of all values in an array larger than a value in another cell

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm perfectly aware of the `sumif()` Function in Google Sheets.

```
A   B  

1  15  
2  20  
2  10  
3  30  
5  45  
1  10
```

When I want to calculate the sum of all values in the array smaller then 3, I can use SUMIF(A:A;"<3";B:B) .
When looking for all values equal to another cell value (C1), I can use

```
=SUMIF(A:A;C1;B:B).
```

But I can't find a way to calculate the sum for all values for all cell values smaller then the cell value in C1 `SUMIF(A:A;<C1,B:B)` doesn't work. What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 4):

To sum all values in B:B that correspond with values in A:A that are smaller than a value housed in C1:

`=SUMIF(A:A;"<"&C1;B:B)`